# Why can't I see my table (PostgreSQL) when I use \dt(+) inside psql?

Tags: postgresql, schema, table, psql

I have created the table `donor` in the schema `reference` as per:

```
CREATE TABLE reference.donor (
    donor_code smallint PRIMARY KEY,
    donor_name character varying NOT NULL,
    donor_type smallint REFERENCES reference.donor_type (type_id),
    alpha_2_code char(2) REFERENCES reference.iso_3166_1 (alpha_2_code)
);
```

I have populated the table as per:

```
INSERT INTO reference.donor (donor_code, donor_name, donor_type, alpha_2_code)
SELECT donor_code, donor_name, donor_type, alpha_2_code
FROM reference.donor_template;
```

When I run:

```
\dt+ reference.*
```

inside psql I see the `reference.donor` table:

```
                          List of relations
  Schema   |      Name      | Type  |  Owner   | Size  | Description 
-----------+----------------+-------+----------+-------+-------------
 reference | donor          | table | postgres | 16 kB | 
 reference | donor_template | table | postgres | 16 kB | 
 reference | donor_type     | table | postgres | 16 kB | 
 reference | iso_3166_1     | table | postgres | 48 kB | 
(4 rows)
```

But when I run `\dt+ donor*` (or `\dt(+)`) I don't see the `reference.donor` table:

```
                          List of relations
  Schema   |      Name      | Type  |  Owner   | Size  | Description 
-----------+----------------+-------+----------+-------+-------------
 oecd_cl   | donor          | table | postgres | 16 kB | 
 reference | donor_template | table | postgres | 16 kB | 
 reference | donor_type     | table | postgres | 16 kB | 
(3 rows)
```

Why can I only see the `reference.donor` table if I run `\dt+ reference.*` or `\dt+ *.donor`?
I was expecting `\dt` (or `\dt+`) to display it, but it does not.

My `search_path` includes the schema `reference` & the user `postgres` has all permissions on the schema `reference` and all tables in the schema as per:

```
GRANT ALL ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA reference TO postgres;
```

Just to clarify, I have two `donor` tables, but they are in two different schemas i.e., `oecd.donor` & `reference.donor`. (I can see `oecd.donor` without any problems when I use `\dt(+)` inside psql).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[The documentation on psql explains:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-psql.html)

> Whenever the ***`pattern`*** parameter is omitted completely, the `\d` commands
>   display all objects that are visible in the current schema search path
>   — this is equivalent to using `*` as the pattern. (An object is said to
>   be visible if its containing schema is in the search path and **no
>   object of the same kind and name appears earlier in the search path**.
>   This is equivalent to the statement that the object can be referenced
>   by name without explicit schema qualification.) To see all objects in
>   the database regardless of visibility, use `*.*` as the pattern.

Bold emphasis mine.
Obviously, you have `oecd_cl` before `reference` in your [search path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9067777/939860). Use this for your purpose:

```
\dt *.donor*
```

And you'll get:

```
                          List of relations
  Schema   |      Name      | Type  |  Owner   | Size  | Description 
-----------+----------------+-------+----------+-------+-------------
 oecd_cl   | donor          | table | postgres | 16 kB | 
 reference | donor          | table | postgres | 16 kB | 
 reference | donor_template | table | postgres | 16 kB | 
 reference | donor_type     | table | postgres | 16 kB | 
(4 rows)
```

Comment: OK, I get it. This is a follow up q: if I didn't know that there are two tables with the same name in two different schemas in a DB and wanted to see all the tables in all the schemas in this DB, is there a psql meta command that will display them all, irregardless of which schema is placed in the `search_path` first and without me knowing the table/schema names in advance? Or am I better of querying the `information schema` e.g.,: `SELECT table_schema, table_name FROM information_schema.tables ORDER BY table_schema, table_name;`?

Comment: @user4842454: [The information schema has it's own caveats.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24089729/939860). To see *all* tables (including the system catalogs) use `\dt *.*` as instructed in the quote.

Answer (score 1):

First command works because all listed tables has 'reference' in their schema. Second command works the same for 'donor'. so the relation "reference.iso_3166_1" does not have any 'donor' in its name. if you want to list  iso_3166_1 then just try

```
    \dt+ iso*
```

ref: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-PATTERNS

Comment: The question is why the `reference | donor` is not listed with the 2nd command.

Comment: @SahapAsci: my main concern is about why `\dt` (or `\dt+`) does not list the reference.donor table. All is OK as per the reference.iso_3166_1 table.